# Cloud-installer ubuntu openstack

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack

I was installed openstack cloud-installer in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How i can access to horizon? From IP i can view?

[LINK](http://astokes.org/ubuntu-openstack-installer/)
[DOC](http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Try running `cloud-status`.

Comment: I have url http://10.0.3.20, but it is pending state

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cloud-installer/bin/status-listener", line 86, in <module>
    username, password, host, virtual_host = get_info()
  File "/usr/share/cloud-installer/bin/status-listener", line 35, in get_info
    stderr=STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '['juju', 'run', '--unit', 'glance-simplestreams-sync/0', 'cat /etc/glance-simplestreams-sync/identity.yaml']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: In cloud-status view there are public addresses posted in the statusbar of the screen which will report the horizon dashboard and juju-gui when those nodes become available. the traceback you posted is from one of the charms we deploy to sync the glance images, which could be a result of an issue with the glance node. I suggest heading over to https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/cloud-installer and filing a bug.